# Not able to export the sheet data in web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using a web app which consists search button on top, as per search criteria it will pull the data from a sheet.

After adding the date in sheet (example Date format-1/4/2017), it stopped working.
If i remove the date (column C)then it works perfactly fine

Please help me to fix the issue

Complete code and sample sheet for your reference 
[Sheet][1]

[1]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` and also you need to convert date string to date object. Replace the below lines in code.gs

```
var aData=sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 1, 1,sheetDatabase.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
aData[0][1]= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(aData[0][1]), "GMT +1","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```